# ng-show equal to true if value is true usage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<p ng-show="NotZero">something</p>
```

JS

```
$scope.NotZero == false; // thus it's hidden
$scope.NotZero == true; // thus it's not hidden
```

is this correct usage of ng-show? can NotZero be boolean?

Comment: Yes, you're using it the right way (the angular-way!). NotZero can absolutely be a boolean if you want to ;) Personally I prefer [ng-if](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngIf) which completely remove the element from the DOM but ng-show works great too.

Comment: NotZero can be boolean.

Answer (score 0):

yes it will work!

You can use

```
$scope.NotZero == 0; // thus it's hidden
$scope.NotZero == 1; // thus it's not hidden
```

as well.

Comment: Here, it should = sign only, not ==

Comment: User will usually copy your answer as they are not clear about this so you should give clear answer.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is right.

It will show/hide

element but in you JS, do like this.

```
$scope.NotZero = false; // thus it's hidden
$scope.NotZero = true; // thus it's not hidden
```